# Is it acceptable to overuse secondary indices for maintenance deletions or integrity checks

Tags: cassandra

My data model is, I think, quite good for my normal queries.

However, to ease some maintenance deletions and integrity checks I would be very easy for me to such `where` with a secondary index.

Will this affect the performance of my regular queries?

Answer (score 2):

Likely yes. Even if not using the secondary indexes, keeping them maintained is expensive if they don't fit in the ideal 2i usecase. You can end up with very wide partitions in your indexes if data cardinality is too low which can eat up your compaction executors/throughput. You can end up with huge tables that can eat up memory and index summary space if your cardinality is too high (and the rare reads will be very expensive). Only use secondary indexes if you understand your use case matches the recommendations or your on a small development/toy cluster with little data.